# JavaScript - Forcing redirect if default value is changed in text field on a form

Tags: javascript

I have a form that is dynamically pre-filled with values which on submission does an API call to update a 3rd party database. I'm fairly new to JS, but I have a problem whereby if a colleague sends the form around to others, it'll do an API call to update their contact record and not create a new contact record for anyone that changes the email field.

Is there a way to force a re-direct to a static form URL if someone starts to change the email field?  I was looking at something like:

```
document.getElementById('email').onchange=function()
{
if (this.value != this.defaultValue)
location.href='http://valueinhere'
}
```

I could always trigger a message to popup that explains why the redirect to the static form if need be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="email" value="email.com" firstvalue="email.com" />
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('email').onkeyup = function () {
    var firstvalue = this.getAttribute('firstvalue');
    if (this.value != firstvalue) {
        alert('You will be rediretioned!');
        window.location.href = 'http: //www.valueinhere.com';
    }
};
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wQxsn/)**

I used the onkeyup event instead because the onchange triggers only on blur, so if they change the mail but not click in another input/element nothing will happen.

Keep in mind that changing what would be the expected behavior if a web page is not user friendly. Maybe better with a disabled input field and a button "change" just beside it.

In that case you can use this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="email" value="email.com" disabled="disabled" />
<button type="button" id="mailchange">Change this</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('mailchange').onclick = function () {
    alert('You will be rediretioned!');
    window.location.href = 'http: //www.valueinhere.com';
};
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wQxsn/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Sergio - advice well taken with the 'change' button... that might be a better user experience than suddenly re-directing them!  Let me report back on this but it makes more sense with the keyup function...

Comment: @user2652921, ok. I updated my answer with a example for that also.

Answer (score 0):

in JS, the 'onchange' triggers when the input value is finished changing (i.e, in text input - upon blur). You should maybe want to try using the 'onkeydown' and 'onmouseup' (for copy and paste) events to check the difference between the old value and the current one.